# Верно употребление «не»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

«...насколько бы грозными и непобедимыми не выглядели бы силы зла...» Верно здесь употребление «не»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, неверно. Здесь ни — усилительная частица, поэтому правильно:

> «...Насколько бы грозными и непобедимыми ***ни*** выглядели силы зла...»

Также, по-моему, стоит убрать вторую либо первую частицу бы, одна из них здесь излишня.

Comment: лучше убрать первую

Comment: @m.vokhm почему?

Comment: Я не знаю правила, но на мой слух звучит намного лучше. Более естественная структура предложения.

Comment: @m.vokhm видимо, возможны оба вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: "Насколько" здесь не совсем удачно стилистически (видимо, напрашивается ложное сравнение "на сколько"), лучше заменить на "сколь" или "какими". Положение же частицы "бы", на мой взгляд, правильнее **в начале**, поскольку сослагательность относится здесь не к глаголу (как-нибудь они в любом случае будут "выглядеть"), а к мере "грозности" (грозны, очень грозны, устрашающе грозны...) с "непобедимостью".

Comment: @Alex_ander благодарю за мнение; я бы также поставил «бы» в начало. По моим наблюдениям существует тенденция употреблять «насколько» вместо «сколь» (звучит высокопарно) и «какими». Мне показалось, это не критическая ошибка, поэтому я ее и не выделил.